# How do I add an edit button on each row of a "tableselect" form element?

Tags: forms

How do I add an edit button on each row of a "tableselect" form element?

The code I have is the following one.

```
function example_elements_form() {
    $form = array();
    $header = array(
        'title' => array('field' => 'n.title', 'data' => t('Title')),
        'author' => array('field' => 'u.name', 'data' => t('Author')),
    );
    $query = "SELECT n.nid, n.title, u.name FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {users} u ON n.uid = u.uid". tablesort_sql($header);
    $result = pager_query(db_rewrite_sql($query));
    while($partial_node = db_fetch_object($result)) {
        $options[$partial_node->nid] = array(
            'title' => check_plain($partial_node->title),
            'author' => theme('username', $partial_node),
        );
    }
    if (!empty($options)) {
        $form['nodes'] = array(
            '#type' => 'tableselect',
            '#header' => $header,
            '#options' => $options,
        );
        $form['pager'] = array('#value' => theme('pager'));
        $form['submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Submit'),
        );
    }
    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.admin.inc/function/node_admin_nodes/7

In particular, take a look at the lines that contain "operations". You need to set up a new element in $header to contain a column for the "operations", and then add at least one operation inside $options for each row.

You could either manually add a link to the edit with l(), or you could use module_invoke('node_operations') - again, an example of that is shown in the API.

Comment: Can I use image button instead of using text button for Edit button i.e, i want image instead of "EDIT"

Comment: Sure. You can use the l() function to add a class to your "a" tag, and then you can use CSS to put a background image on it and hide the text.